# Select count by new items added in the past month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following SQL tables ...

```
Country_ID | Country  |
-----------------------
     1     | France   |
     2     | England  |
     3     | Germany  |
     4     | Scotland |
-----------------------


WorkList_ID | Places | DateOfCreation |
----------------------------------------
     1     | France   |    01/02/2018  |
     2     | England  |    11/01/2018  |
     3     | Germany  |    21/02/2018  |
     1     | France   |    13/03/2017  |
     2     | England  |    21/01/2018  |
     4     | Scotland |    04/03/2018  |
     2     | England  |    08/02/2018  |
     3     | Germany  |    13/03/2017  |
     1     | France   |    09/02/2018  |
     2     | England  |    11/03/2017  |
---------------------------------------
```

Using the country a key to link the tables. How can I produce the following table:

```
Country    | Total Count  | New From Last month  |
--------------------------|----------------------
  France   |     3        |        1         |
  England  |     4        |        2         |
  Germany  |     2        |        1         |
  Scotland |     1        |        0         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I want to display the total count of work lists as well as all the new ones that were added in the last month?

Here is what I have so far:

```
  (SELECT Places, COUNT(Places) as 'Outstanding List'

  FROM WorkList
  WHERE Places IN 

  (SELECT Country  FROM tblCountry)

  GROUP BY Places)
```

Comment: How do you define "last month"?

Comment: As a helpful tip, when providing dates, please provide them in a deterministic format. Some of us can't use that data as there aren't 13 months in the year. `yyyyMMdd` is the most preferred format. :)

Comment: Last month would be 1 month ago from today's date.

Comment: Just to clarify the date format is DD/MM/YYYY but I apologise for not making that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job. just a simple `LEFT JOIN` and you can use a `CASE` expression for last month:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE #Country (Country_ID int, Country varchar(10));
INSERT INTO #Country
VALUES (1,'France'),
       (2,'England'),
       (3,'Germany'),
       (4,'Scotland');

CREATE TABLE #Worklist (WorkList_ID int, Places varchar(10), DateOfCreation date);
INSERT INTO #Worklist
SELECT Id, Place, CONVERT(date, Creation,103)
FROM (VALUES (1,'France','01/02/2018'),
             (2,'England','11/01/2018'),
             (3,'Germany','21/02/2018'),
             (1,'France','13/03/2017'),
             (2,'England','21/01/2018'),
             (4,'Scotland','04/03/2018'),
             (2,'England','08/02/2018'),
             (3,'Germany','13/03/2017'),
             (1,'France','09/02/2018'),
             (2,'England','11/03/2017')) WL(ID, Place, Creation);
GO
SELECT C.Country,
       COUNT(WL.WorkList_ID) AS Total,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DateOfCreation >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1,0) AND DateOfCreation < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()),0) THEN WL.WorkList_ID END) AS LastMonth
FROM #Country C
     LEFT JOIN #Worklist WL ON C.Country = WL.Places
GROUP BY C.Country

GO
DROP TABLE #Country;
DROP TABLE #Worklist;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  COUNTRY,
        TOT.TOTAL [TOTAL COUNT],
        LAST.TOTAL [NEW FROM LAST MONTH]
FROM tblCountry T
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Places, COUNT(Places) TOTAL
FROM WorkList W
INNER JOIN tblCountry C ON C.Country = W.Places
WHERE W.DateOfCreation BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY Places) TOT ON TOT.PLACES = T.COUNTRY
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Places, COUNT(Places) TOTAL
FROM WorkList W
INNER JOIN tblCountry C ON C.Country = W.Places
GROUP BY Places) LAST ON LAST.PLACES = T.COUNTRY
```

Answer (score 1):

I used left joins in case you have some countries that do not have any new ones yet. This way you get all of the countries listed even if no orders have been done.

```
SELECT Country, NVL(pt.total_count,0), NVL(nt.new_count,0)
FROM country_table cl
LEFT JOIN (SELECT worklist _id, 
      count(worklist_id) as total_count 
      FROM places_table 
      GROUP BY worklist_id) pt ON pt.worklist_id = cl.country_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT worklist _id, 
     count(worklist_id) as new_count 
     FROM places_table 
     WHERE dataofcreate > yourdate  
     GROUP BY worklist_id) nt ON nt.worklist_id = cl.country_id
```